# Creating a generic filter system to pass into an API request

Tags: c#, api

I am building an application that will interact with an API.
My service layer will call the repository which will request data from the API.
I want to be able to pass filters to the repository and came up with the following. I am just curious if there are better ways of doing this?

First, I created an interface called `IFilter`:

```
public interface IFilter
{
    string GetFilterName();
    string GetFilterValue();
}
```

I then have a bunch of filters, for example:

```
public class CreatedAfterFilter : IFilter
{
    readonly string _name = "CreatedAfter";
    DateTime _value;

    public CreatedAfterFilter(DateTime value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public string GetFilterValue()
    {
        return _value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00");
    }

    public string GetFilterName()
    {
        return _name; ;
    }
}
```

...or

```
public class OrdersFilter : IFilter
{
    readonly string _name = "OrderIdList";
    List<Order> _value;

    public OrdersFilter(List<Order> value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public string GetFilterValue()
    {
        return '[' + String.Join(",", _value.Select(x => x.OrderId)) + ']';
    }

    public string GetFilterName()
    {
        return _name; ;
    }
}
```

When I call my repository, I do something like this:

```
var filters = new List<IFilter>();
filters.Add(new CreatedAfterFilter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-110)));
filters.Add(new OrderFilter(1709359));            
var orders = orderRepository.GetSingleOrder(filters);
```

Then in my code that calls the API, I do this to create the query string:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
   getParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(filter.GetFilterName(), filter.GetFilterValue()));
}
```

Am I on the right track here?
This is my first real time in writing C# an using Interfaces.

Comment: You might want to put something in place that decouples the Filters from the Repository you are using. E.g. if you are interacting with a database using SQL, the translation of the filter is different than translating it to a REST call where OData filters are used.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I on the right track here?

I think you are. Here's how you can use a few *tricks* to make it even shorter.

---

Instead of the interface you can implement what is common in an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Filter
{
    public virtual string Name => Regex.Replace(GetType().Name, $"{nameof(Filter)}$", string.Empty);
    public static implicit operator string(Filter filter) => filter.ToString();
}
```

This means the base class will get the name of the filter from its type and it'll be able to implicitly cast it into a string by calling `ToString`. Now everything the derived class needs to do is to implement its own `ToString`:

```
public class CreatedAfterFilter : Filter
{
    private DateTime _value;

    public CreatedAfterFilter(DateTime value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00");
    }    
}
```

So later in the loop you can just do this:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
   getParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(filter.Name, filter));
}
```

---

If you make the `Name` property virtual you can override it in a derived class if the name of the filter cannot be derived from its type name:

```
public class OrdersFilter : Filter
{
    public override string Name => "OrderIdList";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How cool is that?! Such a good way to learn by getting feedback. Thankyou so much! I really like these ideas.

Comment: Just a question.. Why is the implicit operator string have to be static?

Comment: @Lock I'm sorry, I don't have an explanation for that other than the language requires it that way :-( sometimes it's disturbing but I don't know the design reason. However I think there is probably a logical answer somewhere :-)

Comment: Is there a way to put in the abstract class an override of the ToString for Date types so it always does 'ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00");' on the date object?